# Sometimes get a dataframe returned instead of a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a looping structure in one class that retrieves rows from a dataframe within another class. The rows are retrieved one by one which means they are returned as a Series. I then perform several operations on the Series and then update the original dataframe row with the changes.

All of this works fine 99% of the time, but on very rare occasions instead of getting a Series returned to me I get a dataframe. This makes no sense to me because there are no duplicates so I should get a Series returned to me every single time. Here is basically what im doing:

```
class XYZ:
    state_df = #create dataframe and populate it

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_state(self, rowname):
        return self.state_df.loc[rowname].copy()

    def update_state(self, new_symbol_state):
        self.state_df.loc[new_symbol_state.name] = new_symbol_state

class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process():
        xyz = MyClass.XYZ()
        state_series = xyz.get_state(rowname)
        # do stuff with the dataframe row which should be a series
        # ie: state_series. Then update the original dataframe row
        xyz.update_state(state_series)
```

So like I said, 99% of the time I get a Series returned to me, I perform some operations on it, then I send it back to the original dataframe and all is fine. However every now and again I get a dataframe instead of a series which makes no sense. Even if I print out the dataframe, it shows that it only has one row (ie: no duplicates), therefore it should be a Series?

I need a way to ensure that I ALWAYS get a Series returned to me when calling `state_series = xyz.get_state(rowname)`. Is there a way to make sure I always get a series returned to me? Or at least if I get a dataframe returned to me which only has 1 row, then how do I change it into a Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc[rowname]` would return a DataFrame, if rowname is a list , instead of being a single element. Example -

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  4  5

In [15]: df.loc[0]
Out[15]:
A    1
B    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [16]: type(df.loc[0])
Out[16]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [17]: df.loc[[0]]
Out[17]:
   A  B
0  1  3

In [18]: type(df.loc[[0]])
Out[18]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Since, we cannot see where `rowname` is coming from, I am guessng this could be the issue, you can check, why sometimes `rowname` would be coming as a list, instead of a single value.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't been able to figure out yet exactly where the problem is. But your suggestion is probably correct,...I just have to figure out exactly how this is happening.